# The footnote shows chapter 0

Tags: fancyhdr

My thesis preamble is

```
documentclass[12pt,twoside]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{{images/}}
\usepackage{caption}
%\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{subfigmat} % You can either use subfigmat or subcaption
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{morefloats}
\usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttable}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage[a4paper,width=150mm,top=25mm,bottom=25mm,bindingoffset=6mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead{}
\fancyhead[RO,LE]{Systemic Crisis Transmission: Visualizing Vulnerability}
\setlength\headheight{15pt}
\fancyfoot{}
\fancyfoot[LE,RO]{\thepage}
\fancyfoot[LO,CE]{chapter \thechapter}
\fancyfoot[CO,RE]{Raisul Islam}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}

\usepackage{ltablex}
\keepXColumns
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\captionsetup{font=footnotesize}

\usepackage[round]{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{plainnet}

\title{Thesis}
\author{raisul.islam }
\date{February 2020}

\begin{document}

%\maketitle
\input{chapter/titlepage}
\input{chapter/Abstract}
\newpage
\input{chapter/Literature Review}
\newpage
\bibliography{ref}


\end{document}
```

> The first chapter footer shows **chapter 0**. why? How to begin with
>   Chapter 1. In fact the Literature review is sectioned as **0.1
>   Literature Review**. Why not **1.Literature Review**?

Please help

Comment: What are you using to set the chapter inside `Literature Review.tex`? Is it `\chapter` or `\chapter*` (the starred version)?

Comment: Inside the Literature review.tex I put \section{Literature Review}
\pagestyle{fancy}     and then I keep writing

Comment: You haven't define a chapter yet, so the TeX counter is still at $0$. It will remain at $0$ until you call a `\chapter{}` command.

Comment: Could you suggest, how should the structure be in literature review.tex

Comment: Oh i got it. I just need to replace \section{} with \chapter{}...Thank you so much